functionTimeout not working in local.settings.json Azure Function in my local machine
I'm developing an Azure Function in my local machine using Visual Studio 2022 Community and it has been impossible to me to change the timeout of the function.
I have tried "functionTimeout": "-1" and "functionTimeout": "23:00:00" but they are ignored in my local machine.
I can't upload the Function to Azure because we do not want to spend money an all the prove of concept is in my local machine.
This is my local.settings.json:
    {
      "IsEncrypted": false,
      "functionTimeout": "-1",
      "Values": {
        "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
        "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "dotnet",
        "containerName": "someText",
        "containerNameSaving": "someText",
        "containerFileNameSaving": "someText",
        "storageConnectionString": "someText",
        "phi3Model": "someText",
        "phi3Server": "someText",
        "phi3Temperature": someValue,
        "phi3Num_ctx": someValue
      }
    }


"functionTimeout not working" - what does that mean and how do you know it does not?

You need to add functionTimeout in host.json file instead of local settings file

thank @IkhtesamAfrin that was the correct answer

@Stornu2 Shall I post it as a solution?

@IkhtesamAfrin I have already post it, if you want the points, post it and I will select it as the correct one

I have found the issue, you have to set the time out in the file host.json not in local.settings.json.
I have tried with "functionTimeout": "00:00:01" and "functionTimeout": "00:00:10" and worked properly.
I have test it to, and I have already pass the 30 min default time out.
{
  "version": "2.0",
  "functionTimeout": "23:00:00",
  "logging": {
    "applicationInsights": {
      "samplingSettings": {
        "isEnabled": true,
        "excludedTypes": "Request"
      },
      "enableLiveMetricsFilters": true
    }
  }
}


Unrelated: A 23h timeout? I am somewhat curious ...

@Fildor It Is because I'm doing a test in my machine, the AZ function reads an excel file with sentences and send them to a Phi3:mini model in my machine with a huge prompt, each sentence takes 60 seconds to process and it's 500 so I've put 23h of time out to leave the process running all night, I know I can do it in the cloud but we're doing the test trying not to spend money.

Just a suggestion: Maybe don't iterate the sentences in the function. Make the function only process 1 sentence. Then you have a reasonable timeout but N Invocations. I guess that would be easier to scale later on, too.
